# Downvoting closed questions

Tags: discussion, voting

Should we downvote questions that have been closed (to keep the front page clean)?

Comment: I have been doing that, but I am now reconsidering it because of its effect on migration (see Raphael’s answer and its comments).  Good question!

Answer (score 3):

I would follow the guideline on the tooltip of the voting controls:

> This question is unclear or not useful

If you strongly believe that to be true (strong enough that you're willing to absorb the minimal -1 rep cost of casting a downvote) then you should cast your vote that way.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your answer.  Can a closed question be useful?  For example, when I vote to close a question as being off topic, I do so because I believe that it is off topic, which implies that the question is not useful on this site.  This is why I have been downvoting a question which I believe is off topic, but if there is a case where a closed question is useful, I should be more careful.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, I think a possible example of a useful closed question is when it is a exact duplicate which states the question in another form. Not sure about off-topic cases.

Comment: @Kaveh: Thanks.  Duplicate questions are a good point.

Answer (score 2):

A question might be well posed even if it is off-topic. Since apparently many "wrong-posters" feel offended by heavy downvotes, I think we should not necessarily do so. We should acknowledge that the question was posed in a good way and encourage reposting on/moving to other sites.

In case of moving, will votes be moved, too?

Questions that are *both* off-topic and badly posed should feel our full pressure, though.

Comment: It seems that score is copied upon migration.

Comment: Personally I downvoted a question only if it is in bad-shape, not formulated well, and did not try to improve the quality after some suggestions from other users. Off-topic questions, like @Raphael said, may be migrated to other sites together with the votes; and I'm not sure if one can undo the vote after migration. But downvoting is an efficient way to make an unsuitable question invisible, so I don't know...

Comment: Are you suggesting that we should *never* down-vote well-written off-topic questions? I have fairly often down-voted questions that are off-topic before they have been closed (effectively, giving "virtual vote-to-close"), but I was just wondering if we should keep doing that after closing, too.

Comment: I'd suggest that, yes. See also Jeff's answer: a clear, offtopic questions might be useful on another site, so instead of downvoting, flag for move if there is a suited target or vote for close if there is not.

Comment: I think Raphael has a point here, but IMHO the solution is to ask SE not to transfer votes when migrating a question. The votes a question receives depends on the site and its community and does not represent much on the migrated site, e.g. a question with +5 total vote count on SO might receive 0 votes on cstheory and vice versa.

Comment: @Kaveh: I agree about not transferring votes on migration.  Even ignoring the difference of interest, the scale of votes is also different.